# Android - add views, dynamically, in a child view of a ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-view, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have an `ExpandableListView` and i need to add, on `Button` click, a new view element in the specific childView where the button is placed.

To do that, i created a `TableLayout` where put a row with the view element that i need to add in the childview.

This is my child layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:labelFor="@+id/time_stamp_view"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/info_action_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/action_text"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/action_text"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    </TableLayout>

    <!-- This imageview is the "button" to click -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addTimeImageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableTime"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_time_add"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/info_add_time_image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/info_date1"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addTimeImageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date2_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my custom adapter:

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<Action>> expandableListDetail;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int mViewResourceId;
    private int k = 0;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                 HashMap<String, List<Action>> expandableListDetail,
                                 int viewResourceId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
        this.mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

//    @Override
//    public  int getChildTypeCount(){
//        return 2;
//    }

//    @Override
//    public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
//    {
//        return expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))
//                                   .get(childPosition).getId();
//    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Action expandedListAction = (Action) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        ViewHolder holder;
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterAction = null;
        String[] timeSlot;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        if(expandedListAction.getId() == 1)
            adapterAction = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.actionId1, R.layout.spinner_item);
        else if(expandedListAction.getId() == 20)
            adapterAction = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.actionId20, R.layout.spinner_item);

        if(adapterAction != null)
            adapterAction.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_list_spinner);

        holder.spinnerAction.setAdapter(adapterAction);

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<?>)holder.spinnerAction.getAdapter();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : expandedListAction.getActionToPerform().entrySet()){

            holder.spinnerAction.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>)adapter).getPosition(entry.getKey()));
            timeSlot = entry.getValue();

             //Here i add row to table dinamically, according to data passed to adapter
             //why if add row when inflate layout, the adapter don't do that for each childView because convertview is not null for every child.
             // I can't override getChildTypeCount() because every view is different, not just few.
                for (int t = 0; t < timeSlot.length; t++) {


                    TableRow timeRow = new TableRow(context);

                    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_layout, timeRow, true);

                    EditText timeText = (EditText) timeRow.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                    timeText.setText(timeSlot[t]);

                    holder.tableTime.addView(timeRow);
                }

        }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.spinnerAction)
        Spinner spinnerAction;
        @Bind(R.id.addTimeImageView)
        ImageView imageTimeView;
        @Bind(R.id.tableTime)
        TableLayout tableTime;

        public ViewHolder(View view){ButterKnife.bind(this, view);}
    }
}
```

This code work pretty well, but i need to add a listener on `Imageview` that add a new row in the table. I tried to do in this way(i added this code in getView):

```
        holder.imageTimeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
            Action azione1 = expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).get(expandedListPosition);


            String actionType = null;
            for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : azione1.getActionToPerform().entrySet()) {
                actionType = entry.getKey();
            }

                Action azione2 = new Action();
            azione2.setId(azione1.getId());
            azione2.setGroupAddress(azione1.getGroupAddress());
            azione2.setWeekDay(azione1.getWeekDay());

            Map<String, String[]> actionPerform = azione1.getActionToPerform();
            String[] time = actionPerform.get(actionType);
            String[] time2 = new String[time.length+1];

            time2[0] = "New time"+k;
            k++;
            for(int t=0; t<time.length; t++)
                time2[t+1] = time[t];

            Map<String, String[]> actionToPerform2 = new HashMap<>();
            actionToPerform2.put(actionType, time2);
            azione2.setActionToPerform(actionToPerform2);

      //When i call updateAction, i update the HashMap expandableListDetail passed from ModifyScenarioActivity when i set the adapter,
     //and then i call notifyDataSetChanged() on ExpandableListView adapter.

            ((ModifyScenarioActivity)context).updateAction(azione1, azione2, expandableListTitle.get(listPosition));

            TableLayout table = (TableLayout)parent.findViewById(R.id.tableTime);

            table.invalidate();
            table.refreshDrawableState();

        }
    });
```

This listener doesn't work because it adds the new rows in the table, but the same rows are added to other tables of other child several times.
Can anyone help me handle this situation? I don't know how to solve it. Other approaches are also appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added this statement:

```
            if(holder.tableTime.getChildCount() < timeSlot.length) {
            holder.tableTime.removeAllViews();

//                for (int t = 0; t < timeSlot.length; t++) {
//
//                    TableRow timeRow = new TableRow(context);
//
//                    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_layout, timeRow, true);
//
//                    EditText timeText = (EditText) timeRow.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
//                    timeText.setText(timeSlot[t]);
//
//                    holder.tableTime.addView(timeRow);
//                }
            }
```

Now the table is refreshed but in the other table of other child view, display the same row of the modified child, but I can not explain why, when fill `expandedListAction` with `getChild()`, is called on different listPosition and `expandedListPosition`. I found with debugger that the data are ok.

**EDIT**

I solve the problem deleting, every time getView is called, all the rows in the table and adding again with resfreshed data. So i ask if i can improve scroll performance, maybe without deleting and refreshing table every time.
This is the solution:

```
            holder.tableTime.removeAllViews();
        for (int t = 0; t < timeSlot.length; t++) {

            TableRow timeRow = new TableRow(context);

            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_layout, timeRow, true);

            EditText timeText = (EditText) timeRow.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
            timeText.setText(timeSlot[t]);

            holder.tableTime.addView(timeRow);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best solution but this is the only thing working for me. Thanks a lot. Cheers :)

Comment: pleased that it works :)